# EF Core 5: Configuring owned type with PK same as FK and with no parent property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, .net-5

I'm trying to migrate to EF Core 5. Everything used to work before. I have the following structure that I don't want to change.

ActionSetup.cs

```
public class ActionSetup
{
        public Conditions Conditions { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Conditions
{
       public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

EntityConfiguration.cs

```
public class EntityConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<ActionSetup>
{
        builder.OwnsOne(tah => tah.Conditions, a =>
            {
                a.ToTable("action_conditions");
                a.Property<long>("id");
                a.HasKey("id");
                a.Property(p => p.SomeValue ).HasColumnName("some_value");
            });
}
```

But now, when I try to fetch an ActionSetup, I get an error because EF Core thinks my FK is called `ActionSetupId`. I am not sure how this used to work before but is there a way to make this work, but:

- Without adding a separate FK.
- Without adding a property inside the `Conditions` class?

Comment: What are you migrating from? E.g. EF6 or an earlier EF Core version? Which keys/FKs currently exist in your database?

Comment: Hi @Xerillio, my current version of the package is 2.2.6. And my current database has a single PK which is also the FK, named `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just configure the "ActionSetupId" shadow property to map to "id" in the table.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ActionSetup>()
    .OwnsOne(tah => tah.Conditions, a =>
    {
        a.ToTable("action_conditions");
        a.Property<long>("ActionSetupId").HasColumnName("id");
        a.Property(p => p.SomeValue).HasColumnName("some_value");    
    });
```

creates

```
   CREATE TABLE [action_conditions] (
      [id] bigint NOT NULL,
      [some_value] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_action_conditions] PRIMARY KEY ([id]),
      CONSTRAINT [FK_action_conditions_ActionSetup_id] FOREIGN KEY ([id]) REFERENCES [ActionSetup] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
```